# X3D imagetexture too large for browser

Tags: x3d

I'm creating a panorama in x3d and using a panoramic image as the texture for a sphere. The image I'd like to use for the texture is about 6 megs. This works fine in x3d viewers and chrome, though it takes a couple of seconds to load. Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer will not apply the texture and leave me with a blank sphere. They don't seem to like images above about 2.5 megs.

Does anyone have an idea for a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a limitation in the browser there's nothing you can do but you can find a workaround for this:

1. You could decrease the quality of the image or change some other parameters (compression format) in order to make it smaller (less than 2.5MB).
2. You can split the image into multiple pieces and then apply the separate pieces to the different parts of the sphere so that in the end you fully cover the sphere as you would have only one image being attached to the sphere.

Comment: I thought about trying to split the image. Having gone through the documentation I'm not sure how I would go about splitting it in half. I tried creating to hemisphere's but the image covered the flat bottom.

Comment: you might need to use IndexedFaceSet in order to add the texture in a specific manner. E.g. http://www.web3d.org/x3d-resources/content/examples/ConformanceNist/Geometry/IndexedFaceSet/index.html. Or you can use a tool like 3dsMax where it is much easier to add texture to 3d models and then export it to x3d.